# CodeIgniter - Load View Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

The following code was working correctly without any issue,

```
$this->load->view('profile_js.php', array("js_array"=>$js_array));
```

Suddenly, the above code stopped working for some users, and it started working when I used echoing the file content

```
echo $this->load->view('profile_js.php', array("js_array"=>$js_array), true);
```

The later works well with all the users! So strange! What would have gone wrong?

*Note: The file has no conditions to filter users/user types*

Comment: why r u using true in last param?

Comment: @devpro it will render the html but not send it to the client when you pass true.
OP: Are you doing this in a function that works as a javascript post or get?

Comment: yes @vaishak you are right, after adding this, its not working right when u ECHO or print this?

Comment: @Glubus No, its used as normal. When user 'A' opens the page with first code, it loads the view. Where user 'B' checks, it doesn't get the view content to the page.

Comment: ALright, well you'll need to put your full function in here and your profile_js.php in order for us to further help you I think. I'm sure there's just something you missed as you're mentioning some users do get the content and some dont. Have you checked what the response type is for the users that don't get the content btw?

Comment: .php is not need to load a view

Comment: @saurabhkamble .php is not necessary, I understand. But it won't affect the application.

Glubus, basically that has got nothing other than some JS script. I'm loading the view from another view, this is so strange, it never appeared for me till date!!

Comment: @Vaishak are you using ajax to get this view??

Comment: @Priyank57, no. I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing data

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {

      $js_array = 'some code goes here';

      $data = array(
         'js_array' => $js_array
      );

      // Do not need to use .php for views
      $this->load->view('profile_js', $data);

   }

}
```

Then on the view you can echo out the js_array

```
<?php echo $js_array;?>
```

For more understanding of how to pass data from controller to view correct

[CodeIgniter Controller User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

[CodeIgniter Views User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: thank you!

I'm loading the view from another view, this is so strange, it never appeared for me till date!! Same time it works for another user without echo ing.

Comment: Just noticed it, this is not loading the view due to some error occurred in the previous view files!!

Comment: Got it fixed, it was due to a 403 error in above view!!

Comment: @Vaishak accept this answer. This is correct and its solved your problem too

Comment: @Abdulla, I don't mind accepting, I'm very thankful to people who help!

But for this issue, the answer didn't help me out. This was due to a show_403() code in the above views.

Comment: @Vaishak ah i thought you may forget. ok